# Как задать высоту ячейки в гугл таблицах?

Tags: python, google-spreadsheet

У меня есть таблица в гугл шитс, в ней столбец с картинками и мне нужно в этом столбце изменить ширину и высоту автоматически, это можно сделать? (точнее, это  скорей можно сделать, но через pandas не выходит, прочитал половину документации, гугл, там, только, ширину)

Comment: Почему Вы решили, что pandas может подойти под эту задачу? Вы знакомы с назначением данной библиотеки?

Comment: С его помощью создал дата фрейм, подредактировал файл и записал в эксель

Comment: @DiXaT `Pandas` не про форматирование, она в основном про данные.

Answer (score 1):

Для [gspread](https://github.com/burnash/gspread) работает авторесайз

```py
sht = gc.open_by_key(spreadsheetId)

requests = []

requests.append({
      "autoResizeDimensions": {
        "dimensions": {
          "sheetId": sheetId,
          "dimension": "ROWS",
        }
      }
    })

requests.append({
      "autoResizeDimensions": {
        "dimensions": {
          "sheetId": sheetId,
          "dimension": "COLUMNS",
        }
      }
    })

body = {
    'requests': requests
}

sht.batch_update(body)
```

- `spreadsheetId` - id Таблицы
- `sheetId` - gid листа
- `gc` - авторизованный клиент `gspread`.